# Need help understanding whether internal state of viewModel is automatically updated along with ProtoDataStore

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda, protocol-buffers, higher-order-functions

Working on an android app (personal project) with Kotlin and Jetpack.

Using Proto datastore to store application settings/configurations. Using Hilt for D.I.

My code was just working fine with intended outcomes, I thought to take "suggestions" from ChatGPT for optimizing my code, and ChatGPT presented me with the refactored version of the code.

**
First let me share my code:**

```
@HiltViewModel
class ApplicationEntryViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val protoData: DataStore<GeneralApplicationPreferences>
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _applicationStates = MutableStateFlow(GeneralPreferences())
    val applicationStates
        get() = _applicationStates.asStateFlow()


    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            protoData.data.collectLatest { preferences: GeneralApplicationPreferences ->

                GLOBAL_DATA_PRECISION = protoDataPrecisionToDataPrecision(preferences.dataPrecision)

                _applicationStates.update { currentValue ->
                    currentValue.copy(
                        currentDestination = preferences.currentDestination.ifEmpty {
                            NavigationDestinations.SAMCompanion.screen_route
                        },

                        showTrailingZero = preferences.showTrailingZero,

                        isHCVisible = preferences.isHcVisible,
                        isWFHClassificationEnabled = preferences.isWfhClassificationVisible,

                        isBMIVisible = preferences.isBmiVisible,
                        isGradeVisible = preferences.isGradeVisible,

                        isICDSDataSamplerEnabled = preferences.isIcdsDataSamplerEnabled,
                        isSchoolDataSamplerEnabled = preferences.isSchoolDataSamplerEnabled
                    )
                }
            }
            SHOW_TRAILING_ZERO = _applicationStates.value.showTrailingZero
        }
    }

    private suspend fun toggleShowICDSDataSampler (isEnabled: Boolean) {
        _applicationStates.update { value ->
            value.copy(
                isICDSDataSamplerEnabled = isEnabled
            )
        }

        viewModelScope.launch {
            protoData.updateData { preferences: GeneralApplicationPreferences ->
                preferences.copy {
                    this.isIcdsDataSamplerEnabled = _applicationStates.value.isICDSDataSamplerEnabled
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun toggleShowSchoolDataSampler (isEnabled: Boolean) {
        _applicationStates.update { value ->
            value.copy(
                isSchoolDataSamplerEnabled = isEnabled
            )
        }

        viewModelScope.launch {
            protoData.updateData { preferences: GeneralApplicationPreferences ->
                preferences.copy {
                    this.isSchoolDataSamplerEnabled = _applicationStates.value.isSchoolDataSamplerEnabled
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun updateCurrentDestination (destinationRoute: String?) {
        _applicationStates.update { currentValue ->
            currentValue.copy(
                currentDestination = destinationRoute ?: NavigationDestinations.SAMCompanion.screen_route
            )
        }

        viewModelScope.launch {
            protoData.updateData { preferences: GeneralApplicationPreferences ->
                preferences.copy {
                    this.currentDestination = _applicationStates.value.currentDestination
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun icdsToggleHCVisibility (isVisible: Boolean) {
        _applicationStates.update { currentValue ->
            currentValue.copy(
                isHCVisible = isVisible
            )
        }

        viewModelScope.launch {
            protoData.updateData { preferences: GeneralApplicationPreferences ->
                preferences.copy {
                    this.isHcVisible = _applicationStates.value.isHCVisible
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun icdsToggleWFHClassificationVisibility (isVisible: Boolean) {
        _applicationStates.update { currentValue ->
            currentValue.copy(
                isWFHClassificationEnabled = isVisible
            )
        }

        viewModelScope.launch {
            protoData.updateData { preferences: GeneralApplicationPreferences ->
                preferences.copy {
                    this.isWfhClassificationVisible = _applicationStates.value.isWFHClassificationEnabled
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun schoolToggleBMIVisibility (isVisible: Boolean) {
        _applicationStates.update { currentValue ->
            currentValue.copy(
                isBMIVisible = isVisible
            )
        }

        viewModelScope.launch {
            protoData.updateData { preferences: GeneralApplicationPreferences ->
                preferences.copy {
                    this.isBmiVisible = _applicationStates.value.isBMIVisible
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun schoolToggleGradeVisibility (isVisible: Boolean) {
        _applicationStates.update { currentValue ->
            currentValue.copy(
                isGradeVisible = isVisible
            )
        }

        viewModelScope.launch {
            protoData.updateData { preferences: GeneralApplicationPreferences ->
                preferences.copy {
                    this.isGradeVisible = _applicationStates.value.isGradeVisible
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun updateDataPrecision (newPrecision: DataPrecision) {
        GLOBAL_DATA_PRECISION = newPrecision

        viewModelScope.launch {
            protoData.updateData { preferences: GeneralApplicationPreferences ->
                preferences.copy {
                    this.dataPrecision = GLOBAL_DATA_PRECISION.toProtoDataPrecision()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun toggleShowSchoolHeightInFPS (inFPS: Boolean) {
        _applicationStates.update { value ->
            value.copy(
                showSchoolHeightInFPS = inFPS
            )
        }

        viewModelScope.launch {
            protoData.updateData { preferences: GeneralApplicationPreferences ->
                preferences.copy {
                    this.showSchoolHeightInFps = _applicationStates.value.showSchoolHeightInFPS
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun toggleShowTrailingZeroAfterDecimal (showTrailingZero: Boolean) {
        _applicationStates.update { value ->
            value.copy(
                showTrailingZero = showTrailingZero
            )
        }

        SHOW_TRAILING_ZERO = showTrailingZero

        viewModelScope.launch {
            protoData.updateData { preferences: GeneralApplicationPreferences ->
                preferences.copy {
                    this.showTrailingZero = _applicationStates.value.showTrailingZero
                }
            }
        }
    }

    suspend fun handleEventsFor (event: PreferenceEvents) {
        when (event) {
            is PreferenceEvents.DestinationChanged ->           updateCurrentDestination(event.destination)
            is PreferenceEvents.ToggleBMI ->                    schoolToggleBMIVisibility(event.isBMIVisible)
            is PreferenceEvents.ToggleGrade ->                  schoolToggleGradeVisibility(event.isGradeVisible)
            is PreferenceEvents.ToggleHC ->                     icdsToggleHCVisibility(event.isHCVisible)
            is PreferenceEvents.ToggleWFHClassification ->      icdsToggleWFHClassificationVisibility(event.isWFHClassificationEnabled)
            is PreferenceEvents.ToggleShowHeightInFPS ->        toggleShowSchoolHeightInFPS(event.showHeightInFPS)
            is PreferenceEvents.ToggleTrailingZero ->           toggleShowTrailingZeroAfterDecimal(event.showTrailingZero)
            is PreferenceEvents.ToggleGlobalDataPrecision ->    updateDataPrecision(event.precision)
            is PreferenceEvents.ToggleICDSDataSampler ->        toggleShowICDSDataSampler(event.isDataSamplerEnabled)
            is PreferenceEvents.ToggleSchoolDataSampler ->      toggleShowSchoolDataSampler(event.isDataSamplerEnabled)
        }
    }

}

data class GeneralPreferences (
    val currentDestination: String = NavigationDestinations.School.screen_route,

    val isICDSDataSamplerEnabled: Boolean = false,
    val isHCVisible: Boolean = false,
    val isWFHClassificationEnabled: Boolean = false,

    val isSchoolDataSamplerEnabled: Boolean = false,
    val isBMIVisible: Boolean = false,
    val isGradeVisible: Boolean = false,

    val showSchoolHeightInFPS: Boolean = false,

    val showTrailingZero: Boolean = false,
)
```

**GLOBAL_DATA_PRECISION** and **SHOW_TRAILING_ZERO** - these two are global variables

**ChatGPT's refactored code:**

```
@HiltViewModel
class ApplicationEntryViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val protoData: DataStore<GeneralApplicationPreferences>
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _applicationStates = MutableStateFlow(GeneralPreferences())
    val applicationStates
        get() = _applicationStates.asStateFlow()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            protoData.data.collectLatest { preferences ->
                handleDataStoreUpdate(preferences)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun handleDataStoreUpdate(preferences: GeneralApplicationPreferences) {
        GLOBAL_DATA_PRECISION = protoDataPrecisionToDataPrecision(preferences.dataPrecision)

        _applicationStates.value = preferences.toGeneralPreferences()

        SHOW_TRAILING_ZERO = _applicationStates.value.showTrailingZero
    }

    private suspend fun updatePreference(
        updater: suspend (GeneralPreferences) -> GeneralPreferences,
        updaterProto: suspend (GeneralApplicationPreferences) -> GeneralApplicationPreferences
    ) {
        _applicationStates.value = updater(_applicationStates.value)

        viewModelScope.launch {
            protoData.updateData { preferences ->
                updaterProto(preferences)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun GeneralApplicationPreferences.toGeneralPreferences(): GeneralPreferences {
        return GeneralPreferences(
            currentDestination = currentDestination.ifEmpty { NavigationDestinations.SAMCompanion.screen_route },
            isICDSDataSamplerEnabled = isIcdsDataSamplerEnabled,
            isHCVisible = isHcVisible,
            isWFHClassificationEnabled = isWfhClassificationVisible,
            isSchoolDataSamplerEnabled = isSchoolDataSamplerEnabled,
            isBMIVisible = isBmiVisible,
            isGradeVisible = isGradeVisible,
            showSchoolHeightInFPS = showSchoolHeightInFps,
            showTrailingZero = showTrailingZero
        )
    }

    suspend fun handleEventsFor(event: PreferenceEvents) {
        when (event) {
            is PreferenceEvents.DestinationChanged -> updatePreference(
                { it.copy (currentDestination = event.destination) },
                { it.copy { currentDestination = event.destination } }
            )
            is PreferenceEvents.ToggleBMI -> updatePreference(
                { it.copy (isBMIVisible = event.isBMIVisible) },
                { it.copy { isBmiVisible = event.isBMIVisible} }
            )
            is PreferenceEvents.ToggleGrade -> updatePreference(
                { it.copy (isGradeVisible = event.isGradeVisible) },
                { it.copy { isGradeVisible = event.isGradeVisible} }
            )
            is PreferenceEvents.ToggleHC -> updatePreference(
                { it.copy (isHCVisible = event.isHCVisible) },
                { it.copy { isHcVisible = event.isHCVisible} }
            )
            is PreferenceEvents.ToggleWFHClassification -> updatePreference(
                { it.copy (isWFHClassificationEnabled = event.isWFHClassificationEnabled) },
                { it.copy { isWfhClassificationVisible = event.isWFHClassificationEnabled} }
            )
            is PreferenceEvents.ToggleShowHeightInFPS -> updatePreference(
                { it.copy (showSchoolHeightInFPS = event.showHeightInFPS) },
                { it.copy { showSchoolHeightInFps = event.showHeightInFPS} }
            )
            is PreferenceEvents.ToggleTrailingZero -> updatePreference(
                { it.copy (showTrailingZero = event.showTrailingZero) },
                { it.copy { showTrailingZero = event.showTrailingZero} }
            )
            is PreferenceEvents.ToggleGlobalDataPrecision -> updatePreference(
                { it } ,
                { it.copy { dataPrecision = event.precision.toProtoDataPrecision()} }
            )
            is PreferenceEvents.ToggleICDSDataSampler -> updatePreference(
                { it.copy (isICDSDataSamplerEnabled = event.isDataSamplerEnabled) },
                { it.copy { isIcdsDataSamplerEnabled = event.isDataSamplerEnabled} }
            )
            is PreferenceEvents.ToggleSchoolDataSampler -> updatePreference(
                { it.copy (isSchoolDataSamplerEnabled = event.isDataSamplerEnabled) },
                { it.copy { isSchoolDataSamplerEnabled = event.isDataSamplerEnabled} }
            )
        }
    }
}

data class GeneralPreferences (
    val currentDestination: String = NavigationDestinations.School.screen_route,

    val isICDSDataSamplerEnabled: Boolean = false,
    val isHCVisible: Boolean = false,
    val isWFHClassificationEnabled: Boolean = false,

    val isSchoolDataSamplerEnabled: Boolean = false,
    val isBMIVisible: Boolean = false,
    val isGradeVisible: Boolean = false,

    val showSchoolHeightInFPS: Boolean = false,

    val showTrailingZero: Boolean = false,
)
```

Both the versions are working as intended.

What I observed in the following line (of ChaGPT's code):

`is PreferenceEvents.ToggleGlobalDataPrecision -> updatePreference( { it } , { it.copy { dataPrecision = event.precision.toProtoDataPrecision()} } )`

At this point I am unable to understand how come the GLOBAL_DATA_PRECISION is getting updated in the ChatGPT's code. Which led me to believe that if ProtoDataStore is updated the rest of the state variables are also automatically updated. Am I right? Or I got the whole thing wrong?